# Is there any limit on Active eventListeners in a namespace on OKD

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, okd, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have twenty different repositories for the twenty separate services to be deployed on an OKD cluster. I want to create separate eventListener for each repository/service. The first eventListener and all it's related components (Deployment, Pod, Service) are successfully created and the eventListener status becomes active, but on deploying more eventListener, eventListener is created but none of the related resources like (Deployment, Pod, and Service) are created and the status is Empty. Here I am sharing the eventListener YAML file.

```
---
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: EventListener
metadata:
  name: el-name
  namespace: namespace-name
spec:
  serviceAccountName: pipeline
  triggers:
    - triggerRef: trigger-reference-name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by updating my Trigger code, to filter the repository names, so that just the pushed repository can start the pipeline.

```
    ---
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Trigger
metadata:
  name: trigger-name
  namespace: namespace-name
spec:  
  nodeSelector:
    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker-serial=worker2 
spec:
  serviceAccountName: pipeline
  interceptors:
    - ref:
        name: "cel"
      params:
        - name: "overlays"  
          value:
            - key: X-Hub-Signature
              expression: "1234567"
        - name: "filter"
          value: "header.match('X-Event-Key', 'repo:push') && body.push.changes[0].new.name=='dev'"
        
        - name: "filter"
          value: "header.match('X-Event-Key', 'repo:push') && body.repository.full_name=='org-name/service-name'"
  bindings:
    - ref: binding-sample
  template:
    ref:  tt-sample
```

Thanks @SYN for some useful hints.

Comment: nice job, have fun with tekton!

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit. There could be a resourcequota, preventing you from scheduling more pods, or requesting more cpu/memory?

Although from your post: I would suggest you try to use a single EventListener, with multiple triggertemplate, ... receiving it all in one place, if possible

Comment: There is a problem with using singl eventlistener, it triggers all the templates in response rebuilding all the services, where the change is coming from one repo. I can't find any way to add conditions so that all the templates are not triggered.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your TriggerTemplate. I can confirm to you I'm using EventListeners with tens of triggers and different pipelines. Works great. No more than one pipelinerun starting per payload received.  Regardless: you should be able to create as many EL as you need in the same namespace.

Comment: ok, Can you please share your trigger template OR the idea how a signle pipelinerun starts depending on the payload

Comment: something like this: https://gist.github.com/faust64/49717e97483f25baa91870496e4faac0 . which might need some integration based on your ecosystem ... also, they released v1beta1?, I'm still using v1alpha1 ATM, ... shouldn't be much different. Use interceptors. Look at the payload you received, instead of just always starting the same pipeline.

Comment: check the docs, they do give samples, I can see lots of nice things I wasn't aware of, eg trigger groups: https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/main/docs/eventlisteners.md#specifying-triggergroups